# Django Development Server, blank HttpResponse on Post Method

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-views

I am developing an application in Django using Heroku's tools and guides for doing so, and have ran into an issue. On my local dev environment I cannot get a response from my views if it I use the post method. Currently i'm using a simple form to post a collection of ids to a view.

```
def webinarToHS(request):
errors = []
if request.method == 'GET':
    webinars = get_upcoming_webinars()
    return render_to_response('webinarToHS.html', {'webinars': webinars.json(), 'length': len(webinars.json())/2}, RequestContext(request))
elif request.method == 'POST':
    method = request.method
    return HttpResponse("test")
```

In the console it comes back with a 200 response ok. However the browser displays a blank html page (empty body tags).

On the production/heroku server, i get back a response, so I don't believe there is an issue with the code itself but rather with my settings file. I went back through the heroku django setup guide and used an environment variable on my local machine to switch those settings off if i'm in local dev but I am still having this issue.

Can anyone give me a clue as to where to start looking for a fix? I'm running windows 7 with a virtualenv wrapper, python 2.7.5 and django 1.5

Thanks.

As per requested in the comments, the WebinarToHS template file is as below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Add Webinars to Hubspot</title>
    <style>
        html, body {background-color: #eee;}
        #wrapper {background-color: #fefefe; width:60%; margin:0 auto; position:relative; margin-top:50px; padding:25px;}
        form {text-align:center;}
        label {font-weight:bold;}
        .submit {float:right;}
        .check {float:left; text-align:left; max-width:48%; margin-right:2%;}
    </style> 
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <form name="form" action="{%url 'G2WApi.views.webinarToHS' %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <label for="webinarKey">Choose the Webinar(s) you would like to add to hubspot:</label><br/><br/>
                <div class="check">
                {% for webinar in webinars %}
                    <input type="checkbox" name="webinars[]" value="{{ webinar.webinarKey }}" />{{ webinar.subject }}<br/>
                    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:length %}
                        </div><div class="check">
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both; height:10px;"></div>
            <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Add to Hubspot" />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: share your `webinarToHS.html` template file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it doesn't actually solve the question at hand, I found a way that was much better for what I was trying to do. I discovered that everything in my code for the POST Method worked except the output or rendering of a template. HttpRedirection worked, and also the Django Messages System. I found a tutorial on how to use that and it works perfectly for posting responses back to the originating template.

The Django Messaging system, for those who aren't aware, is a way to add details back to the originating request object. Here's a snipper

```
messages.success(request, "success message")
return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)
```

The first line of code is attaching the message to the request object (in this case the same one that was passed in to the view) and then in the second line of code we are just redirecting back to the requesting path. Django handles all the rest you just have to add some code to your template like follows:

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
  {% for message in messages %}
  <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

to loop through and display your messages however you wish. I hope this helps someone.